# Hibernate + Sybase Iq

Tags: hibernate, orm, sap-iq

I have completed my hibernate project on sql server and now we have to shift from sql server to sybase iq. I have all my queries written in hql and no logic in sql server. Does hibernate supports Sybase Iq? So that i do not have to change anything in my application other than Sybase Iq configurations. Its a bit of priority so please respond fast in case you know. Have searched a lot but not much response.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you have to get and configure the correct jdbc driver ([jconnect](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1600/doc/html/san1357754910584.html) directly from Sybase or [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) which is open source) and change your Hibernate dialect (`hibernate.dialect` property) to `org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I am pretty sure it works for Sybase ASE . So have you tried connecting to sybase iq via hibernate not sybase ase but sybase iq.The dialect you mentioned is for sybase ase thas why i asked.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Hibernate driver for SQL Anywhere. SQL Anywhere lives inside IQ and provides the native SQL dialect for IQ (Watcom SQL). A variant of ASE's T-SQL dialect is also supported by SQL ANywhere (and IQ), but this is not enabled by default (unless you connect with TDS instead of the native SQL anywhere protocol).  In other words, you may also try the SQL Anywhere Hibernate dialect with IQ. I guess you can see which one works best

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try this and update the post with results. I was kinda worried i will have to let go of hibernate because of using iqq.